# How can I add a hover event to multiple paths in a SVG? And have it work in IE9?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg

I have been trying to figure out how I can create a hover event that controls multiple paths in an SVG.  In the map of the US I am creating, Alaska, Hawaii, and Michigan are grouped elements containing multiple paths.  I have been able to add a hover event using CSS, but when I hover over the states with grouped elements only the path that I am hovering over changes.  When I hover over them, I would like to be able to have all paths in the appropriate grouped state change as if they a single path.

It seems as if using CSS does not allow the cohesiveness that I am searching for.  Maybe jQuery?  I have searched for a jQuery solution, but I read somewhere that jQuery does not work well inside SVGs.  I tried SMIL, but it does not seem to work well with IE9.

Can someone help me come up with a solution that will work in IE9 and the latest Chrome, Safari, and Firefox browsers?

The SVG file is linked below. Any help you can provide will be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

http://sample.charlesjoyner.com/20150121-usa-map.svg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Alaska is in a `<g>` you can apply the hover to that...

```
    #Alaska:hover{fill-opacity:0.1; cursor:pointer;}
```